# Program throws unhandled exception IndexOutOfRange when I run it

Tags: c#

The code is supposed to start at the biggest value (minValue) and compare each item in the array to it. If the item is smaller than minValue it is assigned to minValue and so on.

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] array=new []{76,78,98,34};
        int minValue=Int32.MaxValue;//maxvalue reassignes itself for each array[index] smaller than minvalue
        foreach(int index in array){
            if (array[index]<minValue)
               minValue=array[index];
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(minValue);
    }
}
```

So why does it throw an unhandled exception? I don't get it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: foreach(int index in array), this doesnt work as an indexer. index will contain the values of array

Comment: the `index` in your loop won´t be an actual **index**, but just the number within the array, e.g. 76. Just use `if(index < minValue)`.

Comment: I said that I have run it. I ran it on repl.it. It shows Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: `minValue = array.Min();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case index does not save the INDEX, but the VALUE. Therefore in the fist iteration, you have `index=76`, and you try to access `array[76]` but the array has only 4 elements, thus the exception.

So to find the min you can either do something like:

```
foreach(int element in array){
        if (element <minValue)
           minValue=element ;
    }
```

Or if you want to iterate via index:

```
for(int index=0; index<array.Length; index++){
        if (array[index]<minValue)
           minValue=array[index];
    }
```

Or make use of Linq instead `minValue = array.Min()`

Answer (score 2):

index isn't the index of your array in the code you've written. It is, instead, the element of the array. So you're going to get array[76] in the first iteration (which, of course, doesn't exist). So it should be more like:

```
foreach (int element in array) {
  if (element < minValue) {
     //Do stuff
  }
}
```

if you want to go by using for instead of foreach it would be:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++) {
   if (array[i]<minValue) {
      //Do stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] array=new []{76,78,98,34};
        int minValue=Int32.MaxValue;//maxvalue reassignes itself for each array[index] smaller than minvalue
        foreach(int index in array){
            if (index<minValue)
               minValue=index;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(minValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work simply because of these lines:

```
foreach(int index in array){
        if (array[index]<minValue)
```

In the foreach you say: "Take one by one every element from array"
And then you do: "Take the index-th element in the array", which in your case is 76 for the first run.
To fix it you should write:

```
 foreach(int index in array){
        if (index < minValue)
           minValue=index;
    }
```

or

```
 for(int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++){
        if (array[index] < minValue)
           minValue=array[index];
    }
```